# dc js select menu and styling with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dc.js, crossfilter

I have started with [this](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/select.html) example from the docs, and attempted to style the selects with bootstrap. In order to get consistent results for testing I have used LCG from answer 8 on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript) SO Post, to seed the RNG.

For styling purposes I have added

```
bootstrap-select.min.css
bootstrap-select.min.js
```

Full code available here: http://jsfiddle.net/r7e2cnyx/60/

If I don't attempt to enable the select picker all works as expected:

[image: no styles enabled]

when enabling the styling in document ready like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//note select1 is a div and .dc-select is the select added by dc
$('#select1 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});

$('#select2 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});

$('#select3 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});

})
```

and select [A] from the first dropdown and [Alice Blue] from the second drop down you get a result like this

*note the items are sorted differently in the color box*
[image: dropdown selection]

and if you click Select All, you get

[image: dropdown selection result]

Note choosing the same options without styles seems to indicate values are being sorted differently after styles are applied. Alice Blue is first in the styled version but Cornflower is first in the non styled shown here
[image: comparison]

I am not sure where the apparent sorting is going on but it appears that bootstrap is doing it or there is an interaction between crossfilter/dc/and bootstrap that is not clear.

In addition there seems to be no way to remove the *Select All* option or make it actually select all the options and make the checks show up.

Is there any other way to attack either of these issues this that I am not thinking of?  Or something that I should be doing that I am not?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see a sorting problem (although it took me a good while to figure out why the wrong options were being selected).

The problem is that you need to manually tell bootstrap-select to refresh whenever the underlying options change.

I prefer to do all mods in response to events - here postRender and postRedraw are pretty good for this:

```
selectm1.on('postRender', function() {
$('#select1 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});
})
.on('postRedraw', function() {
$('#select1 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker('refresh') 
});

selectm2.on('postRender', function() { 
$('#select2 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});
})
.on('postRedraw', function() {
$('#select2 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker('refresh') 
});
selectm3.on('postRender', function() {
$('#select3 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 10
});
})
.on('postRedraw', function() {
$('#select1 .dc-select-menu').selectpicker('refresh') 
});

  dc.renderAll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/a7bwtxgr/23/

Comment: AWESOME ! Thanks.

Comment: The select all is still a bit twitchy have to work on it There is an example out there that replaces with check boxes that i may try. Is it possible to remove the select all? ( i think the code for the check boxes is commented out right now(

Comment: Yeah I don't think select all makes much sense here. I figured out a workaround to get rid of it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774492/676195  you'd do this before each time you apply selectpicker

Comment: selectm1.select('.dc-select-menu').attr('data-actions-box','true')  trying to let the bootstrap select all option work but i can't get it to render  from the bootstrap docs setting that data attribute should show the box but no matter what event i put it in it will not render.. SO very close

Comment: GOT IT  http://jsfiddle.net/a7bwtxgr/71/ hope this helps someone else thanks Gordon for your help.  Select all makes sense when it is a hierarchy like facility/dept/date which mine will be.. I think this will work great