# textfilter for select menu dropdown dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Can I create text filter/search option for the select menu? I have more than 1000 elements listed in the menu, want to use the search option rather than scrolling through.

The select menu was created using this link https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.selectMenu.html

I wanted a functionality similar to this using dc.js/crossfilter
[image]

Comment: I don't know of anything out of the box to do this, but it reminds me of this question/answer, how to integrate jquery checkbox menu with `dc.selectMenu`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811672/dc-js-select-menu-and-styling-with-bootstrap & I think you should be able to solve your problem in a similar way, seeing as you probably want to populate your menu with dc.js but drive the ui using jquery ui (or something similar)