# How to remove additional prompt option "Select all" from dc.js selectMenu?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dimension with the values A,B,C,D.

I would like to create a selectMenu with dc.js, where

- the value A is selected by default
- only one value can be selected (no mulit-selection)
- always one value has to be selected

a) I used `.multiple(false)` and expected that a single value is selected by default.
However, the default state of the menu is to select all available options (=no filtering).

b) I also tried to set the `promptTitle` and `promptValue` to my wanted initial value A.
Also see doc at https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/SelectMenu.html

However, then the option A is displayed twice (and applying the initial value does not work either):

```
let typeSelection = dc.selectMenu('#type'); 

typeSelection.dimension(typeDim)                         
             .multiple(false)
             .group(typeGroupCount)
             .title(d => d.key)
             .promptText('A')
             .promptValue('A')
             .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

[image]

c) I also tried to use the method `filterDisplayed`. However, only the single options are passed as arguments and there does not seem to be a way to disable the 'Select all' option here.

Comment: Your solution works fine, but here’s your duplicate question. I changed the title to make it easier for people to find in the future. I haven’t tested it, but you should be able to set the default onRender. All dc.js charts default to no filter, and it’s possible to initialize them, so I don’t think adding an option would be a good idea.

Comment: Having an option to remove the prompt might make sense, but only in conjunction with a default, so probably not worth it. There’s always a workaround because dc.js is a leaky abstraction by design!

Comment: Thank you. The suggested solution based on the pretransition event does not work for me. In order to illustrate its remaining issues I posted a full example at the duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746692/change-text-and-remove-select-all-from-dc-selectmenu

Comment: >All dc.js charts default to no filter, and it’s possible to initialize them
Maybe I do not fully understand that concept, yet. Is there some doc on this topic? Maybe there are two types of dimensions: a) Dimensions  where it makes sense to do some sort of aggregation and where I would like to be able to select multiple values to change the scope of the aggregation and b) Dimensions, that should not be aggregated. Always only one distinct switch/enum value should be selected. The values are mutually exclusive and split the data in separate (maybe independent) parts.

Comment: Sorry but please don’t post another question as an answer - it makes things very confusing as there is no way to answer it. You could edit this question or ask another one. I flagged your non-answer for deletion. (But I’ll still take a look.)

Comment: I don't disagree, but it's so easy to initialize a selection/filter that there hasn't been any reason to codify this idea of a "single mutually exclusive selection" dimension. You just call `.filter('default')` (or replaceFilter). And there is always a way to customize charts so that only one thing is selected. Beyond the crossfilter stuff, dc.js is not heavy on concepts, there's just lots of tweaks. It would be great to have more how-to documentation for dc.js but SO has pretty much taken over that role. :)

Comment: In my opinion that answer is a long comment. Just wanted to show, that the suggested answer does'nt work. I'll delete it after you had a look.

Comment: I understand, it would be nice to be able to comment in long form. Personally I miss the days of mailing lists, but the world is what it is. I have no way to post an answer to your answer, so please post another question and refer to the previous question. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW it does seem to work fine as long as you initialize the filter as I showed in my previous comment. It's just if the select menu is currently set to a value that's not in the list and it redraws that there are problems.

Comment: Ok. The initialization works now. How can I ensure, that that initialization is run again, after a user changes for example the color filter? I moved my long comment to my answer below.  Please have a look again and feel free to adapt my answer B until it works fine.

Comment: Please apply the filter to the chart, not the dimension. dc.js is not able to read selections from crossfilter.

Comment: Awesome, now it works. :) Thank you again. (I was wondering which chart you mean. Its the selection menu where the filter needs to be applied.) I'll update the answers.

Answer (score 1):

A. Here is a manual implementation of a single selection combo box:

```
<div>
    <label>Type</label>
    <select id='type' style='padding:5px;'>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

-

```
dc.renderAll();

d3.select('#type')
  .on('change', applyTypeSelection);

applyTypeSelection();

function applyTypeSelection(){
    let selectedType = d3.select('#type').node().value;
    typeDim.filter(type => {
      return type === selectedType;
    });
    dc.redrawAll();                
}
```

B. Here is a full example for another approach. It is based on the `pretransition` event that is used in the answer of the old duplicate question

[Change text and remove Select All from dc.selectMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746692/change-text-and-remove-select-all-from-dc-selectmenu)

```
dc.selectMenu('#type') 
  .dimension(typeDim)                         
  .multiple(false)
  .group(typeGroupCount)
  .title(d => d.key)
  .on('pretransition', event => {
        typeSelection.select('option[value=""]')
   .remove();
   })
   .filter('A');
```

```html
<html>

 <head>

  <title>dc demo</title>

  <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF8'>

  <!-- this demo is based on following tuturials:
     https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dcjs/dcjs_introduction_to_d3js.htm 
     https://www.codeproject.com/articles/693841/making-dashboards-with-dc-js-part-1-using-crossfil  
     -->

      



   <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
   <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.5.2/crossfilter.min.js'></script>
   <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.min.js'></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.css" />

 </head>
 
 <body>
     
     <div style="font-family:arial;">

    <div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
    <div >
     <label>Number of colors:</label>
     <div id='color-chart-count'></div>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label>Value sum for colors:</label>
     <div id='color-chart-value-sum'></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
    <div>
     <label>Number of ages:</label>
     <div id='age-chart-count'></div>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label>Value sum for ages:</label>
     <div id='age-chart-value-sum'></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div style="float:left;padding:10px;">
    <div>
     <label>Type</label>
     <div id="type"></div>
     <!--
     <select id='type' style='padding:5px;'>
         <option>A</option>
         <option>B</option>
         <option>C</option>
         <option>D</option>
     </select>
     -->
    </div>
   </div>

     </div>
     
     
        <div style="font-family:arial; float:left">
            <label for='value-chart'>Values:</label>
         <div id='value-chart'></div>
        </div>
     
 
  <script>
   
   let data = [                 

        {color: 'red', age: 1, type: 'A', value: 10},
        {color: 'red', age: 1, type: 'B', value: 11},
        {color: 'red', age: 1, type: 'C', value: 12},
        {color: 'red', age: 1, type: 'D', value: 13}, 

        {color: 'red', age: 2, type: 'A', value: 20},
        {color: 'red', age: 2, type: 'B', value: 21},
        {color: 'red', age: 2, type: 'C', value: 22},
        {color: 'red', age: 2, type: 'D', value: 23},

        {color: 'red', age: 3, type: 'A', value: 30},
        {color: 'red', age: 3, type: 'B', value: 31}, 
        {color: 'red', age: 3, type: 'C', value: 32},
        {color: 'red', age: 3, type: 'D', value: 33},
            

        {color: 'green', age: 1, type: 'A', value: 100},
        {color: 'green', age: 1, type: 'B', value: 105},
        {color: 'green', age: 1, type: 'C', value: 110},
        {color: 'green', age: 1, type: 'D', value: 115},        

        {color: 'green', age: 2, type: 'A', value: 120},
        {color: 'green', age: 2, type: 'B', value: 125},
        {color: 'green', age: 2, type: 'C', value: 130},
        {color: 'green', age: 2, type: 'D', value: 135},        

        {color: 'green', age: 3, type: 'A', value: 140},
        {color: 'green', age: 3, type: 'B', value: 145},
        {color: 'green', age: 3, type: 'C', value: 150},
        {color: 'green', age: 3, type: 'D', value: 155},


        {color: 'blue', age: 1, type: 'A', value: 300},
        {color: 'blue', age: 1, type: 'B', value: 305},
        {color: 'blue', age: 1, type: 'C', value: 310},
        {color: 'blue', age: 1, type: 'D', value: 315},

        {color: 'blue', age: 2, type: 'A', value: 320},
        {color: 'blue', age: 2, type: 'B', value: 325},
        {color: 'blue', age: 2, type: 'C', value: 330},
        {color: 'blue', age: 2, type: 'D', value: 335},

        {color: 'blue', age: 3, type: 'A', value: 340},
        {color: 'blue', age: 3, type: 'B', value: 345},
        {color: 'blue', age: 3, type: 'C', value: 350},
        {color: 'blue', age: 3, type: 'D', value: 355},
      ];

            //create instance of cross filter
   let cf = crossfilter(data);    

            //define dimensions and groups
            let colorDim = cf.dimension(d=> d.color);
            let colorGroupCount = colorDim.group().reduceCount();
            let colorGroupValueSum = colorDim.group().reduceSum(d => d.value);

            let ageDim = cf.dimension(d=> d.age);
            let ageGroupCount = ageDim.group().reduceCount();
            let ageGroupValueSum = ageDim.group().reduceSum(d => d.value);

            let typeDim = cf.dimension(d=> d.type);
            let typeGroupCount = typeDim.group().reduceCount();
            let typeGroupValueSum = typeDim.group().reduceSum(d => d.value);

            let colorAgeDim = cf.dimension(d => [d.color, d.age]);


            function reduceAdd(previous, current) {

             if(current){
              if(current.value !== null){
               if(previous.sum === null){
                previous.sum = current.value;
                previous.count = 1;
               } else {
                previous.sum += current.value;
                previous.count += 1;

               }
              } 
             } 
             return previous;                     
   }

   function reduceRemove(previous, current) {     
    if(current){
              if(current.value !== null){
               if(previous.sum !== null){
                previous.sum -= current.value;
                previous.count -= 1;
                if(previous.count === 0){
                 previous.sum = null;
                }
               } 
              } 
             } 
             return previous;     
   }

   function reduceInit(previous) {
     return { 
             sum: null,
             count: 0
            };
   }
                  
            let colorAgeGroup = colorAgeDim.group()
                                        .reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInit);

            let filteredColorAgeGroup = removeMissingEntries(colorAgeGroup);

            function removeMissingEntries(sourceGroup) {
    return {
     all:function () {
      return sourceGroup.all().filter(function(d) {       
       return d.value.sum !== null; 
      });
     }
    };
   }

            let ordinalColors =  ['red','green','blue'];    
            let ordinalAgeColors =  ['lightgray','grey','#666666']; 
            let ordinalTypeColors =   ['#ffff0020','#ffff0050','#ffff0090', '#ffff00'];                  

            //color charts

            let rgbColorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(ordinalColors).range(ordinalColors);

            let colorChartCount = barChart('#color-chart-count')               
    .xAxisLabel('Color')             
    .x(d3.scaleBand().domain(ordinalColors))  
    .dimension(colorDim)  
    .yAxisLabel('Count')     
    .group(colorGroupCount)       
    .defineColors(rgbColorScale);    

   colorChartCount.yAxis().ticks(4);  
    

   barChart('#color-chart-value-sum')               
    .xAxisLabel('Color')                   
    .x(d3.scaleBand().domain(ordinalColors))  
    .dimension(colorDim)  
    .yAxisLabel('Value sum')    
    .group(colorGroupValueSum)
    .defineColors(rgbColorScale);    

            //age charts

            let ageColorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain([1,2,3]).range(ordinalAgeColors);

          

   let ageChartCount = barChart('#age-chart-count')              
    .xAxisLabel('Age')                    
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,2,3]))  
    .dimension(ageDim)  
    .yAxisLabel('Count')    
    .group(ageGroupCount)   
    .defineColors(ageColorScale);

   ageChartCount.yAxis().ticks(4); 

   barChart('#age-chart-value-sum')               
    .xAxisLabel('Age')             
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,2,3])) 
    .dimension(colorDim)  
    .yAxisLabel('Value sum')    
    .group(ageGroupValueSum)
    .defineColors(ageColorScale);

            //type selection   
            
            //dc selection menu
            //also see https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/SelectMenu.html#undefined 
            //and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746692/change-text-and-remove-select-all-from-dc-selectmenu
              
            dc.selectMenu('#type')
              .dimension(typeDim)                         
              .multiple(false)
              .group(typeGroupCount)
              .title(d => d.key)
              .on('pretransition', event => {
    typeSelection.select('option[value=""]')
       .remove();
     })
              .filter('A');

   //helper functions

   function barChart(elementSelector){

    let barChart = dc.barChart(elementSelector)
     .width(200)
     .height(200)    
     .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)     
     .margins({top:10,left:40,right:5,bottom:35}) 
     .barPadding(0.1)
     .outerPadding(0.1)     
     .transitionDuration(500);

     barChart.defineColors = function(colorScale){
      
      this.renderlet(chart=>{
          chart.selectAll('rect.bar')
            .each(function(d){

                                    let isSelected = this.classList.contains('selected');
                                    if(isSelected){
                                        d3.select(this).attr('style', 'fill: ' + colorScale(d.x) + ';stroke-width:2;stroke:#39ff14');
                                       
                                    } else {
                                     d3.select(this).attr('style', 'fill: ' + colorScale(d.x));
                                    }

            
            });
         
         });
         return this;
     }

     return barChart;
   } 

             
             //value chart
             let chart = dc.seriesChart('#value-chart');

    chart
    .width(500)
    .height(500)
    .chart( c => 
           dc.lineChart(c)
           .renderDataPoints(true)
                          
            
    )    
    .xAxisLabel('Age')
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,3]))
    .dimension(colorAgeDim)    
    .yAxisLabel('Value')
    .elasticY(true)
    .group(filteredColorAgeGroup)     
    .brushOn(false) 
    .clipPadding(10)
    .mouseZoomable(true)
    .seriesAccessor(d => d.key[0])
    .keyAccessor(d => d.key[1])
    .valueAccessor(d => {
     return d.value.sum;
    })
    .ordinalColors(['blue','green','red'])
    .legend(dc.legend().x(430).y(350)); 
   
            
            dc.renderAll();

            

           
                        
            

            //dimensions can also be used for filtering:
            
            //let color_red = colorDim.filter('red');           
            //let filterResult = JSON.stringify(color_red.top(Infinity)).replace('[','[\n\t').replace(/}\,/g,'},\n\t').replace(']','\n]');
            //console.log(filterResult);

            //let functionFilter = ageDim.filter(age => age === 2);  
            //let functionFilterResult = JSON.stringify(functionFilter.top(Infinity)).replace('[','[\n\t').replace(/}\,/g,'},\n\t').replace(']','\n]');
            //console.log(functionFilterResult);


  </script>
 
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting both of your answers!!